# How can i pass N number of variables for testing in parameterized googletest?

Tags: c++, googletest, parametrized-testing

I am using gtest for unit testing. I have to call a lot to arrays to test. But I am not figuring out how i can pass `N - number of variables` in `'INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P'` to test.

I have simply created two arrays `array1` and `array2` and I am passing these two array in the field `'testing :: Values'` of `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P` to test both of them and this test is working fine.

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(
        ParameterizedTest,
        TestParam,
        testing :: Values(
                   array1,array2
                   ));
```

I want to create `N`-number of arrays like `array1,array2,...,arrayN`. But I do not know how i can pass them in the field `testing :: Values` of `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P` to test all of these N arrays.

Comment: Array of arrays? Or rather vector of vectors? Then you only pass a single argument. Or do you really need to pass all the arrays to a single call, can't you pass one array and call the function multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to gather all arrays in one class/struct, then have that struct passed as the parameter.

For anything more advanced, consult the "Parameter generator" section at https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md